# Ошибка recaptchaV3 при запросе на получение токена

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, recaptcha, captcha

На сайте есть форма регистрации. Валидация на фронте отсутствует, есть валидация на беке. При отправке формы с ошибками происходит обновление токена и id скрытого поля re-captcha.

```
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
  grecaptcha.execute(array[0], {action: 'register'}).then(function (token) {
    console.log(token)
    $("[name='g-recaptcha-response']").val(token);
    $("[name='g-recaptcha-response']").attr("id", array[1]);
  });
});
```

При первом запросе она обновляет токен у скрытой формы и можно повторно отправить форму. Но при второй ошибке и повторному обращению к этой функции для замены токена в форме вылезает ошибка:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: reCAPTCHA client element has been removed: 100000.
```

Используется RecaptchaV3. Пробовал делать reset() и тд. Ничего не спасло ситуацию.

Comment: _«Пробовал делать reset() и тд.»_ - пробуй еще... метод `reset` вообще помогает, т.е. вероятно что-то было сделано неправильно при его вызове.

Comment: Может быть. Если написать grecaptcha.reset(). А потом вызвать grecaptcha.ready(function()) то просто ошибка что No reCAPTCHA clients exist.

Comment: _«No reCAPTCHA clients exist»_ - о, знакомая фигня :) такая ошибка может быть при отсутствии элемента (`.g-recaptcha`) или при "потере" апишкой ключа сайта... в некоторых случаях (ключ в атрибуте) это одно и то же, но бывает и иначе. При сбросе рекапчи производишь какие-то операции с DOM? Вообще, желательно добавить минимальный пример попыток заюзать `reset` (дописать в вoпрос участок разметки и код) - проверить здесь вживую не получится, но может удастся визуально определить проблему. Пока что симптомы указывают именно на удаление элемента рекапчи.

Comment: С этой jQuery вообще просто грохнуть элемент по случайности, слишком много лишней магии понапихано в нее :) Один неаккуратный вызов метода, и хэллоубаги))

Comment: Вообще по сути у recaptchaV3 нету же метода reset(), это использовалось в recaptchaV2. Тут же нужно просто обновить токен у скрытого input в форме? '<input type="hidden" name="" id="" value="token">, делаю запрос как описан в вопросе. Первый раз токен подставляется. Второй раз нет. А что я должен сбрасывать reset'ом? Просто не шарю в JS.

Comment: Через jQuery просто делаю подстановку в инпут токена

Comment: Как это нет метода... сейчас посмотрел на одном из подопечных сайтов - есть он)) Только вот я не уверен, имеет ли этот метод эффект в "невидимом" режиме, т.к. сбрасывал им только виджет (ну галочку эту бесячую, знаешь наверное). _«нужно просто обновить токен у скрытого input в форме?»_ - да, и затем вызываешь `execute` (это обычное использование без сброса). _«А что я должен сбрасывать reset'ом?»_ - сие тайна... этот метод сбрасывает какое-то внутреннее состояние рекапчи (хз какое).

Comment: grecaptcha.reset() пишу и если следом execute, то ошибка No reCAPTCHA clients exist. Стало быть клиент удаляется)

Comment: _«нужно просто обновить токен у скрытого input в форме?» - да, и затем вызываешь execute_. А я в самом execute обновляю токен, разницы же нету. Получаю токен и сразу через jQuery подставляю.

Comment: Еще интересно влияет ли на что-то **action** в grecaptcha.execute(array[0], {**action:**. И какой тогда нужно ставить для обновления токена

Comment: Глянул документацию - по идее вообще не должно быть никакого "client element" при вызове `execute`. Элемент рекапче нужен только при автоматическом вызове (с указанием всех ее данных в атрибутах). Соответственно, `reset` в сценарии вызова `execute` не нужен. Вывод: проверь разметку на наличие элементов с классом `g-recaptcha` и убери этот класс везде... самостоятельно вызывая `execute` при попытке отправки. _«влияет ли на что-то action»_ - влияет только на аналитику (вообще я не вникаю во всякие сеошные дела, но по-моему это примерный аналог goal в Метрике).

Comment: Другими словами, варианта два: либо класс `g-recaptcha` на кнопке (и тогда никаких игр с токенами в JS) - либо удаление везде этого класса, и в обработчике события `submit` формы такой порядок действий `preventDefault` ► `ready`+`execute` ► манипуляции с полями формы ► `yourFormElem.submit();`.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Классов с g-recaptcha не было, были инпуты с name="g-recaptcha-response" и id="g-recaptcha-response_{id}", убрал везде g-recaptcha. И все заработало)), кто бы мог подумать, нигде инфы не нашел до этого. Очень много времени потратил на поиск причины.....

Comment: Отлично :) Напиши ответом, пожалуйста, какие правки решили проблему - это может оказаться полезным для тех кто столкнется с такой же ситуацией.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решена проблема удалением всех сочетаний "g-recaptcha" из атрибутов name, id, class.